# AppWidgets transform into Google Calendar and Clock widgets after reboot

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-broadcast, android-appwidget

I have no idea why this is happening. I'm making widgets which show the best currency rate for the currencies that the user chooses. I've noticed after a reboot, they sometimes turn into a clock and a calendar widget. Here's my code. I assume it could be something with my Intents or OnReceive() but I'm not sure what.

```
public class LightRowWidget extends RowWidget {
List<CurrencyObject> currencyObjects = new ArrayList<>();

public LightRowWidget() {
    super(R.layout.widget_row_layout, R.color.white, Constants.FULL_OPACITY, R.color.black);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    if (appWidgetIds != null && appWidgetIds.length > 0) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            // Create currencyObjects. They're used to assign the correct value
            // to the correct texView
            CurrencyObject currObj1 = new CurrencyObject(
                    R.id.currency1, R.id.currency1_buy, R.id.currency1_sell);
            currencyObjects.add(currObj1);
            CurrencyObject currObj2 = new CurrencyObject(R.id.currency2, R.id.currency2_buy, R.id.currency2_sell);
            currencyObjects.add(currObj2);

            // Register an onClickListener to Update the current widget on a click
            Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, LightRowWidget.class);
            clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

            onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, currencyObjects, clickIntent);
        }
        //start an intent that will schedule the alarm for the next update

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, LightRowWidget.class);
        scheduleNextUpdate(context, startIntent, appWidgetIds);
    }
```

and Here is my RowWidget class with the relevant code.

```
public abstract class RowWidget extends AppWidgetProvider implements WidgetInterface{

public RowWidget(int layout, int background_color, int background_opacity, int text_color){
    super();
    this.layout = layout;
    this.background_color=background_color;
    this.background_opacity=background_opacity;
    this.text_color=text_color;

}



public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, List<CurrencyObject> currencyObjects, Intent clickIntent) {
    theAppWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;

    //Get the current name of class
    String currentClass = this.getClass().getName();
    switch(currentClass){
        case("foobar"):
            configure_class=Constants.FOUR_ROW_CONFIGURE;
            break;

        case("foo"):
            configure_class=Constants.ROW_APP_WIDGET_LIGHT_CONFIGURE;
            break;

        case("bar"):
            configure_class=Constants.ROW_APP_WIDGET_DARK_CONFIGURE;
            break;
        case("barfoo"):
            configure_class=Constants.TWO_ROW_CONFIGURE;
            break;

    }
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    // Get the preferred Currencies
    Set<String> preferredCurrencies = AppWidgetConfigure.loadCurrencyPref(context,appWidgetId, configure_class);

    // Inflate the layout
    RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layout);

    // if the preferred Currencies have been declared already
    if(preferredCurrencies!= null){
        // Set the currencies for each object
        for(String currency: preferredCurrencies){
            if(currencyCount<currencyObjects.size()){
                currencyObjects.get(currencyCount).setCurrencyType(currency);
                currencyCount+=1;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        for(CurrencyObject curObj:currencyObjects){
            curObj.setCurrencyType("RUB");
        }
    }
    // Open up the Currency fragment on the click of the widget
    Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    configIntent.putExtra("LaunchCurrency", true);
    configIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.row_widget_layout, configPendingIntent);

    // Update the widget whenever refresh button clicked
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, clickIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh, pendingIntent);


    makeRequest(context, theDate, view, currencyObjects, appWidgetId);
    currencyCount = 0;

}
//Handle receiving the intent
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE)) {
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        // Get id's
        int[] allWidgetIds = intent
                .getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
        onUpdate(context, manager, allWidgetIds);
    }
    else{
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }


}
```

EDIT: Widgets transform to a lot of different widgets that are already on my screen.

Comment: That's, um, interesting. What are you testing this on? Device or emulator? Do you have instances of those other Widgets already on your home screen when yours change? Are those the only kinds of Widgets they change into? What's your app's package name?

Comment: I'm testing it on my device. I do have instances of those other widgets already on my homescreen, on another page. I have other widgets on my screen but two times now, my widgets have transformed into the calendar and the clock only. After another reboot, they turn back to normal

Comment: This really seems like an issue with your device's launcher/home screen, not necessarily your app. It sounds like it's somehow losing track of Widgets, or mixing up which Widgets it's got where. What exactly are you running on? That is, device model and specific OS?

Comment: I'm running it on a One Plus 3, Android 8.0, OxygenOS 5.0.3

Comment: You might try testing on a few emulators, as well. If you can't reproduce it on those, then I'd say it's just some glitch somewhere in that particular setup.